# How to get the managed metadata type(share point) values via rest api on spfx vue js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sharepoint, spfx

How to fetch the Managed metadata types values using API's in spfx on Vue js? 
How can I get the actual values using API on

listUrl = context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + 
   "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + list +"')/items?$select*";

```
return context.spHttpClient.get(listUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,h)
.then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
    return response.json();
});
```

Result is:
Country: Object
Label: "2"
TermGuid: "250b31ef-1d2d-482b-99a2-5743ddad9f85"
WssId: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the hidden field TaxCatchAll for this secenario,

My test demo.

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('testlist')/items?$select=ID,Title,MetaField,TaxCatchAll/ID,TaxCatchAll/Term&$expand=TaxCatchAll
```

Here is the referenced thread.

https://sympmarc.com/2017/06/19/retrieving-multiple-sharepoint-managed-metadata-columns-via-rest/